# Detectar qual o último dia do mês

Tags: r, data

No início do mês sempre preciso calcular a idade das pessoas dentro de uma determinada base de dados. Sempre faço considerando a última data daquele mês, por exemplo: em setembro calculei a idade usando data de 30 de setembro como referência, logo todos que nasceram dentro deste mês eu considero com um ano a mais completo.
Há alguma função que me retorne a data final de determinado mês para eu possa automatizar a tarefa, ou terei que fazer manualmente?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Com a seguinte função, você consegue os últimos dias dos meses seguintes a um determinado último dia de mês

```
seq_monthly <- function(from,length.out) {
  return(from %m+% months(c(0:(length.out-1))))
}
```

Ela utiliza a função `%m+%` do pacote `lubridate`. Você pode então criar um vetor com todos os últimos dias de um determinado ano

```
seq_monthly(as.Date("????-01-31"),length.out=12)
```

e indexar dentro da sua função o mês de referência. Achei essa função em um tópico do SO em inglês.